# Matriz - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matriz

Estou fazendo um trabalho de faculdade que exige que eu faça o jogo do Space Invaders. Consegui fazer a matriz do jogo e agora preciso colocar as naves dentro dela, por enquanto está assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso imprimir as naves de modo que elas fiquem assim:

V V V V

V V V V

Obs: Eu atribui 'V' à nave.

Alguém poderia me dar uma ideia de como eu poderia fazer isso?

Matriz:

```
matriz = []
for i in range(LINHA_MAXIMA+1):
    matriz.append([' ']*(COLUNA_MAXIMA+1))
```

Impressão da matriz:

```
for linha in matriz:
    print("|", end="")
    for posicao in linha:
        print(posicao, end="")
    print("|", end="")
    print("")
```

Comment: Você preenche a matriz ? Ou executa esses dois blocos em sequência ?

Comment: Preenche a matriz

Comment: Como está a preencher a matriz ?

Answer (score 0):

Vamos supor que você tenha uma lista de tuplas que indique a posição de cada nave

```
pos_naves = [(4,3), (5,3), (6,3)]
```

Onde pos_naves[1] = (4,3) dá a posição da nave 1 (x=4, y=3), como você já tem a matriz, basta colocar alterar os caracteres (valores) dessas posições
por 'V'

```
for x, y in pos_naves:
  matriz[x][y] = 'V'
```

Depois, basta desenhar a matriz de novo, seria bom colocar o trecho de código que faz isso em uma função, já que toda vez que você atualizar o estado do jogo, precisa atualizar a interface (esse padrão de projeto é conhecido como MVC: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVC)

Para as naves ficarem na formação que você quer:

0..1..2.3 <---Colunas

V V V V  <--- Linha 0

V V V V  <--- Linha 1

Você teria uma lista parecida com isso

```
pos_naves = [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)]
```